# How to delete rows from a dataframe if specific columns contains null values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete rows from a dataframe if specific columns contains null values:

-> In this example, if col2 and col3 are null:

```
import pandas as pd

obj = {'col1': [1, 2,7,47,12,67,58], 'col2': [741, 332,7,'Nan',127,'Nan',548],  'col3': ['Nan', 2,74,'Nan',127,'Nan',548] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=obj)



df.head()
    col1 col2   col3
0   1    741    Nan
1   2    332    2
2   7    7      74
3   47   Nan    Nan
4   12   127    127
5   67   Nan    Nan
6   58   548    548
```

After delete, the result should be:

```
df.head()
        col1 col2   col3
    0   1    741    Nan
    1   2    332    2
    2   7    7      74
    4   12   127    127
    6   58   548    548
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: You need "any two rows" to be Null for you to delete the row, or values on specific columns ?

Comment: If two specific columns are null I want to delete all rows that have this condition.In this example if col2 and col3 are null I want to delete all the line that has this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [DataFrame.isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) or [`DataFrame.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to check NaN or Null values.
Select the maximum number of `NaN` allowed per rows with [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) and [`Series.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
new_df=df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1).le(1)]
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   col1   col2   col3
0     1  741.0    NaN
1     2  332.0    2.0
2     7    7.0   74.0
4    12  127.0  127.0
6    58  548.0  548.0
```

---

> To specifict columns:

## [DataFrame.all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

```
df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
df_filtered=df[~df[['col2','col3']].isnull().all(axis=1)]
print(df_filtered)

   col1   col2   col3
0     1  741.0    NaN
1     2  332.0    2.0
2     7    7.0   74.0
4    12  127.0  127.0
6    58  548.0  548.0
```

Comment: If two specific columns are null I want to delete all rows that have this condition.In this example if col2 and col3 are null I want to delete all the line that has this condition. Sorry, I already edited a question.

Comment: I did the following and it didn't work out:: df2= df.drop(df[(df.col2.isnull()) & (df.col3.isnull())].index)

Answer (score 1):

Using [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna)

`axis = 0` to delete rows, `thresh=1` has the number of non-null values required to drop the row.

You can use `subset=['col2', 'col3']` if you want to define the columns on which the as the basis of dropping rows.

You can try this:

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['col2', 'col3'], how="any", thresh=1)
```

Comment: I did the following and it didn't work out:: df2= df.drop(df[(df.col2.isnull()) & (df.col3.isnull())].index)

Comment: If two specific columns are null I want to delete all rows that have this condition.In this example if col2 and col3 are null I want to delete all the line that has this condition. Sorry, I already edited a question.

Comment: @Gizélly Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

After deploying the solution proposed by @ansev, everything worked:

```
import pandas as pd

obj = {'col1': [1, 2,7,47,12,67,58], 'col2': [741, 332,7,'Nan',127,'Nan',548],  'col3': ['Nan', 2,74,'Nan',127,'Nan',548] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=obj)

df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
df_filtered=df[~df[['col2','col3']].isnull().all(axis=1)]

print(df_filtered)

col1   col2   col3
0     1  741.0    NaN
1     2  332.0    2.0
2     7    7.0   74.0
4    12  127.0  127.0
6    58  548.0  548.0
```