# Pandas DataFrame - how to drop the entire category containing null values for specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have the following DataFrame:

| book | page | words_per_page | characters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Book 1 | 1 | 27 | Nan |
| Book 1 | 2 | Nan | 30 |
| Book 1 | 2 | 30 | 25 |
| Book 2 | 1 | 30 | 26 |
| Book 2 | 2 | 28 | 30 |

How can I delete the books containing at least one null value for either `Words Per Page` or `Characters`? In the above situation, I want to drop all the entries associated with Book 1.

It is a combination between these two questions, but I just couldn't get it right yet.

[pandas How to drop the whole row if any specific columns contains a specific values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673494/pandas-how-to-drop-the-whole-row-if-any-specific-columns-contains-a-specific-val)

[How to delete rows from a dataframe if specific columns contains null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630044/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-dataframe-if-specific-columns-contains-null-values)

It should be a way to do it directly on the dataframe. I have lots of data and I need to make this run as efficiently as possible, I'm trying to avoid `if` statements outside of the dataframe.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify book ids that match that criteria and filter the DF using those book ids, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 1, 27, None],
    [1, 2, None, 30],
    [1, 2, 30, 25],
    [2, 1, 30, 26],
    [2, 2, 28, 30]
]

columns = [
    'book_id',
    'page_number',
    'words_per_page',
    'character_count'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df = df[~df.book_id.isin(
    df[
        (df.words_per_page.isna()) |
        (df.character_count.isna())
    ].book_id
)].copy()
```

```
   book_id  page_number words_per_page  character_count
3  2        1           30.0            26.0
4  2        2           28.0            30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could find the rows which have either of the two values as NaN, then exclude those from your df using the `~` operator

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'book': ['Book 1', 'Book 1', 'Book 1', 'Book 2', 'Book 2'],
 'page': [1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
 'words_per_page': ['27', np.nan, '30', '30', '28'],
 'characters': [np.nan, '30', '25', '26', '30']})

books_with_nulls = df.loc[df[['words_per_page','characters']].isnull().any(axis=1)]['book'].unique()
df.loc[~df['book'].isin(books_with_nulls)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` and `filter` which removes entire groups/books that fail the filter. Here the filter is that each book group has to be `notnull` in `all` values for `Words_per_page` and `characters`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'book': ['Book 1', 'Book 1', 'Book 1', 'Book 2', 'Book 2'],
    'page': [1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
    'words_per_page': [27, np.nan, 30, 30, 28],
    'characters': [np.nan, 30, 25, 26, 30]
})

filt_df = (
    df.groupby('book').filter(
        lambda b: b['words_per_page'].notnull().all() and b['characters'].notnull().all() 
    )
)

filt_df
```

`groupby.filter` is notoriously slow on large datasets, not sure if it will be fast enough for your usecase

Comment: Yes, group by would work, I was trying to avoid it however (I do have large dataset). I'll wait to see if there are any other ideas before doing it this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

or if only subset of columns to be checked for null values

```
df.dropna(subset=['words_per_page','characters'], axis=0, how='any')
```

```
    book    page    words_per_page  characters
2   Book 1    2                 30          25
3   Book 2    1                 30          26
4   Book 2    2                 28          30
```